# Error adding Date to DB using Angular and Java EE

Tags: java, angular, date

For a simple Customer Management App I am having trouble adding the date of birth!

here is my html:

```
<label for="dob" class="firstThreeInputs">Date of Birth: </label>
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="customer.dateOfBirth" class="" id="dateOfBirthInput" name="dateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
```

When I add a new customer or edit an existing one I get the following error:

```
Failed executing PUT /customers/6: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-12-12')
```

Looks like this is a common issue and there is a solution with Jackson but I cannot figure out how to implement that in my application.

Below is my Customer class:

```js
import java.time.LocalDate;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

//Data and Integration

@Entity
@Table(name ="basic_info")
@NamedQuery(name="Customers.selectAll", query="SELECT n From Customers n")
public class Customers {
 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Column(length=100, nullable=false)
 private String first_name;
 
 @Column(length=100, nullable=false)
 private String last_name;
 
 @Column(length=100, nullable=false)
 private String country_code;
 
 @Column(length=100, nullable=false)
 private String gender;
 
 @Column(nullable=false)
 private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
 
 @Column(nullable=false)
 private boolean isActive;
 
 
 public Customers() {}
 
 public Customers(Long id, String first_name, String last_name, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
  this.id = id;
  this.first_name = first_name;
  this.last_name = last_name;
  this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
 }
 
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 
 public String getFirstName() {
  return first_name;
 }
 
 public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
  this.first_name = first_name;
 }
 
 public String getLastName() {
  return last_name;
 }
 
 public void setLastName(String last_name) {
  this.last_name = last_name;
 }
 
 public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
  return dateOfBirth;
 }
 
 public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
  this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
 }
 
 public String getCountryCode() {
  return country_code;
 }
 
 public void setCountryCode(String country_code) {
  this.country_code = country_code;
 }
 
 public String getGender() {
  return gender;
 }
 
 public void setGender(String gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
 }
 
 public boolean getActiveStatus() {
  return isActive;
 }
 
 public void setActiveStatus(boolean isActive) {
  this.isActive = isActive;
 }
 
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Cusomters [id=" + id + ", First Name =" + first_name + ", Last Name=" + last_name + " DateOfBirth="+ dateOfBirth +" Gender= " + gender + "CountryCode=" + country_code + "]";
 }

 
}
```

How do I add the Jackson code so that my JSON gets converted to Java at PUT/POST and the other way around during a GET? How do I use the ObjectMapper and the JavaTimeModule?

Below is my Customer Resource class:

```js
package at.technikumwien.webf;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

@Path("/customers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomersResource {
 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomersResource.class.getName());
 
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em; 
 
 @Inject
 private CustomersService customersService;
 
 @Context
 private UriInfo uriInfo;
 
 @POST
 @Transactional
 public Response create(Customers customer) {
  LOGGER.info("create >> customer=" + customer);
 
  em.persist(customer);
  URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(customer.getId().toString()).build();
  return Response.created(uri).build();
  
 }
 
 @PUT
 @Path("/{id}")
 @Transactional
 public void update(@PathParam("id") long id, Customers customerUpdate) {
  LOGGER.info("update >> id=" + id + ", customer=" + customerUpdate);

  Customers customerOld = em.find(Customers.class, id);
   if ( customerOld != null) {
    customerOld.setFirstName(customerUpdate.getFirstName());
    customerOld.setLastName(customerUpdate.getLastName());
    customerOld.setDateOfBirth(customerUpdate.getDateOfBirth());
    customerOld.setGender(customerUpdate.getGender());
    customerOld.setCountryCode(customerUpdate.getCountryCode());
    customerOld.setActiveStatus(customerUpdate.getActiveStatus());
   }
   
   else {
    throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
   }
 }
 
 
 @DELETE
 @Path("/{id}")
 @Transactional
 public void delete(@PathParam("id") long id) {
  LOGGER.info("delete >> id=" + id);
  
  Customers customer = em.find(Customers.class, id);
  if (customer != null) {
   em.remove(customer);
  }
  else {
   throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
  }
 }
 
 @GET
 @Path("/{id}")
 public Customers retrieve(@PathParam("id") long id) {
  LOGGER.info("retrieve id=" + id); 
  return em.find(Customers.class, id);
 }
 
 
 @GET
 @Path("/")
 public List<Customers> retrieveAll() {
  LOGGER.info("retrieveAll");
  return customersService.getAllCustomers();
 }
 

}
```

Comment: The error says "from String value". You should parse your "string date" to Date.

Answer (score 0):

As your error explains, [the *java.time* classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) such as `LocalDate` have no public constructors. There is no `new LocalDate`. Instead, these classes use [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), as shown in these [naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;  // Tip: Better to pass a `ZoneId`.
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Immutable objects. So a new fresh `LocalDate` is instantiated based on values copied from original object. 
LocalDate someDay = LocalDate.parse( "2020-01-23" ) ;
```

Your code is apparently expecting a [no-arg constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)). Not found, of course.

The topic of [handling `LocalDate` with `Jackson`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20Jackson%20LocalDate&t=osx&ia=web) has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just can't figure out where to do that! I will reframe my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a wonderful blog that explains just that:

https://kodejava.org/how-to-format-localdate-object-using-jackson/